# Prim's algorithm, using a priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to implement prim's algorithm, using a priority queue. When I call offer() method, it gives me a class cast exception, saying that vertex cannot be cast to comparable. Is there a workaround?

```
public static Collection<Edge> prims(Graph g, int start) {
            ArrayList<Edge> mst = new ArrayList<Edge>();
            PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertices = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
            Vertex startVertex;

        for (Vertex vertex : g.getVertices()) {
            vertices.offer(vertex);
            if (vertex.getId() == start) {
                startVertex = vertex;
            }
        }

        if (!mst.isEmpty()) {
            return mst;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prims algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) uses the weight of the **edge** to determine the best path. Posting the vertex to the `PriorityQueue` will not work.

I am guessing your `Edge` class will implement `Comparable` by comparing their lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you need your `Vertex` method to implement `Comparable<Vertex>`.

Java's `PriorityQueue` is an implementation of a heap, which has log-time insertion, and log-time removal of the minimum element. But in order for that to be meaningful, you need to have a notion of *minimum*; and that means you need whatever you put into a `PriorityQueue` to be `Comparable`, so that two elements in the heap can be compared.

The reason that non-`Comparable` elements can be inserted into a `PriorityQueue` is that you can also specify a `Comparator` in the constructor, rather than using `Comparable` elements. So as an alternative, you could leave your `Vertex` class as it is, but use the appropriate constructor (which also requires you to specify an initial capacity):

```
PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertices = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>(11,
    new Comparator<Vertex>() {
        //implement .compare() and .equals()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have your `Vertex` class implement `Comparable`, or to provide a `Comparator` to the priority queue when constructing it. The Java collections framework needs a way to compare your vertices (after all you're putting them into a priority queue and priority implies the necessity of some ordering being present).

Comment: See though the answer from `OldCurmudgeon`. According to it, seems you have an upper-level design flaw in your approach to this problem.